# How to avoid validation message in Spring getting converted from "&" to "&amp;"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am developing a Spring MVC application which support English & Arabic.

I have created `messages_en.properties` and `messages_ar.properties` for both English and Arabic respectively.

In `messages_ar.properties`, I used [Unicode](http://unicode.org/charts/) characters (for e.g. `&#1604`) for Arabic characters.

I use `messages_en.properties` & `messages_ar.properties` for both spring message and validation messages.

This is working fine for `<spring:message code="label.dateTime"/>`, but does not work for validation errors `<form:errors path="*" />`.

I found that `<form:errors path="*" />` transfers unicode from `&#1604` to **`&amp;`**`#1604.`

Has any one faced similar problems and how to avoid Spring's converting the unicode characters?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Did you use `native2ascii` for encode properties files?

Comment: I got encode steps are: 1. Got Arabic statement file. 2. Open this file in Microsoft office word 2007. 3 Seving it as HTML file. 4. Open HTML file in any Editor that you can see all Unicode.

Comment: I tried using native2ascii to converting property file. It is generating Unicode looking like /uxxxx. It is not HTML Unicode characters. The result my page will display ???.

Answer (score 0):

I found problems. It is form errors tag, by default, It sets htmlEscape="ture" which will convert "&" to "&amp". 
To solving this problem. Simply adding attribute htmlEscape="false" to form errors tag.